# How can I call historical series values from a Pinescript array or line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My goal is to call float series values of the array/line values which are plotted using this indicator:

https://www.tradingview.com/v/Y8v4W3mX/

For example, I want to be able to find the highest and lowest point of the current forecast. That way I can use the forecast values within a strategy script.

I tried referencing all the variable names within the code to do this but had no success.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be said in advance, the whole logic of that script plays out on the very last bar (see: `if barstate.islast`). Make sure your strategy has `calc_on_every_tick = true`.
Well, the data is already there you need and you don't necessarily have to extract it from the lines, although that'd be simple too: `line.get_y1(lineId)` - starting price, `line.get_y2(lineId)`- end price. Check the [reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_line%7Bdot%7Dget_y1) for that.
But you can simply do the following:

1. define an array after `prev = src` at best: `pivots = array.new_float(1, src)`
2. after you get the new current value in the for loop, add this value to the array: `array.push(pivots, current)`
3. finally you can get your min and max values after the for loop wherever you want. To also display it for now you can: `label.new(bar_index, array.max(pivots), "Max")`, `label.new(bar_index, array.min(pivots), "Min")`

Comment: Hmmm...so that means I would need to remove the barstate.islast in order to avoid repainting right? Because I think that using calc_on_every_tick=true can cause some unrealistic backtesting data if I'm not mistaken? Also, I tried adding the following outside of the loop, in order to get the float values of the min/max, but it gave me a Undeclared identifier 'pivots' error:

echo_max = array.max(pivots)
echo_min = array.min(pivots)

Comment: It is a difficult task because your source is an indicator which is designed to make the forecast on the very last bar. It can make the forecast only if it receives all the historic data (past days up to evaluation length). So if you want to work with its results, you need to stick to barstate.islast. I would not worry so much beause of the repainting in your case, because your evaluation window is huge in regard to the eventually "fake" last value, so your forecast  should probably not change that much and not to forget, it's a **forecast** that can never be precise.

Comment: So then how can I call on the max value outside of the conditional? I tried adding echo_max = array.max(pivots) outside of the conditional statement, in order to get the float values of the max, but it gave me:
 Undeclared identifier 'pivots' error:  echo_max = array.max(pivots)

Comment: Example:
line 54: pivots = array.new_float(1, src)
line 67: array.push(pivots, current)
line 79/90: echo_max = array.max(pivots), echo_min = array.min(pivots)
pay attention that you refer to pivots within "if barstate.islast" because the variable exists only there. So at least 1 tab before referring to it